# Delay startup application in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, autostart

In Gnome or Unity, you can delay the startup of an application by placing the following file in the following directory:

`~/.config/autostart/firefox1.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application
Name=Firefox
GenericName=Firefox
Comment=Sync Firefox
Exec=firefox ~/Desktop/map.html start -i
Icon=firefox
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10
```

However, the x-gnome-autostart command does not work in xfce in Xubuntu. Is there a way to accomplish this in xfce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a command needs to run on startup (actually log in) you can delay the command in the format:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && firefox"
```

Your entries:

```
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
```

won't hurt, but are unnecessary, they are the default.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using this line as exec works to open it in a terminal

> xterm -e 'sleep 10 && firefox'

Comment: Why run it in a terminal? Run `/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && firefox"`

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get access to the machine again. I tried something like that and it didn't work, but maybe it's because i ommited everything before "sleep"

Comment: Then it won't work indeed :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you! This works outside of terminal. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted