# Delay autostart of programs such as conky and dropbox, in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, dropbox, autostart, conky

Kubuntu 19.10

Like the title says, I want to delay the autostart of certain programs. These programs appear in the GUI of Autostart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay startup application in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809479/delay-startup-application-in-xubuntu)

Comment: Method for delaying autostart works the same in all desktops that adhere to the freedesktop.org specifications, so also in KDE

Comment: @vanadium, Kubuntu is slightly different and so this is not a dupe, in my opinion. Following the process I outlined in the answer results in the system creating its own .desktop file based on what input we provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll share my autostart on 19.10 for conky and on 18.04 for Dropbox.

Autostarting conky in 19.10:

I opened *System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart*

- In there, I clicked on *Add Program ...*
- A window titled "Choose Application -- System Settings" appeared
- I clicked on *Terminal options* but did not tick *Run in terminal*
- In the text box above, I entered `conky --pause=60`¹ and then clicked *OK*
- A new window appeared indicating that the system would create a desktop configuration file titled *conky.desktop* for me in `/home/dkb/.config/autostart`. I clicked *OK*.
- I was taken back to the original *Autostart* screen where I could see, under **Desktop File** an entry for conky.

**Autostart for conky**

[image: Autostart for conky]

¹ A more elaborate command could be one in which you specify the particular conky configuration file you wish to load. So, `conky --pause=60 -c $HOME/.config/conky/clock.conf` would start conky with clock.conf instead of any other configuration file. Using `conky --pause=nn -c $HOME/path/to/another/conky.conf` would allow you have more than one conky active: you'll be specifying the delay (in seconds with `nn`) and the path to the relevant conky configuration file with `-c ...`

(The other entry is for *Latte Dock* and that was created by the `latte-dock` application itself.)

---

In the case of Dropbox in Kubuntu 18.04, I took another route.

I keep all my local executable scripts in `~/bin`. The relevant one is `dropbox.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 60s && cd /home/dkb/.dropbox-dist/ && ./dropboxd
```

So I went through the same process again, but, instead of choosing *Add Program*, I chose *Add script* and pointed to `dropbox.sh`. This time, on completion, the entry was not under **Desktop File** but under **Script File**.

Comment: My dropbox autostart entry says "dropbox start -i" what does that mean?

Comment: According to [this link](https://www.mankier.com/1/dropbox), "`dropbox start [-i]` Starts the Dropbox daemon, dropboxd. If dropboxd is already running, this will do nothing."

Comment: I choose not to start Dropbox that way and I've turned off Dropbox from autostarting in its GUI. That way, I can have the delayed start I prefer. My laptop has an i3 processor and I don't want to burden it at start up time. I guess if you have a more powerful machine, your code is just fine!

Comment: Could you explain the right syntax to start two different conkies that are in separate locations? I have a .conkyrc in Home and a .conkyrc in Documents and I want both of them to run at startup.